# Detect Azure Protected PDF with iTextPDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I try to find a way to detect if a PDF is using Microsoft Azure Protection with iTextPDF and can't find a proper way to do this. Is there some property or something I could use to check if the PDF was created with Microsoft Azure Protection?

Comment: Can you share - for analysis - example PDFs that are using Microsoft Azure Protection?

Comment: No, I don't have an example that I can share on the internet.

Comment: If your "PDFs using Microsoft Azure Protection" are what [this Microsoft Tech Community article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/using-azure-information-protection-to-protect-pdf-s-and-adobe/ba-p/282010) describes, this protection is the standard PDF encryption. Microsoft Azure Protection may or may not leave some indicator that this off-the-shelf encryption was applied by MS Azure Protection. As you cannot share an example here, please analyze your PDFs, look for some such indicator, and describe it here if you found one. Then we can help detecting it.

Comment: Ok, I just read that article till the end. Apparently Adobe Acrobat can recognize that "Microsoft Azure Information Protection" was applied, and apparently some "Azure Information Protection plugin" is required. It's likely that that plugin is a security provider. Thus, I would assume you can recognize PDFs protected like that by the encryption dictionary **Filter** or **SubFilter** entry.

Comment: Since [recently](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/mip-plugin-download.html) the plugin is installed by default...

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any better solution than reading the content as text and looking for an "Azure" string in it.

```
final String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfDoc.getPage(1), new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
if (text.contains("Microsoft \n    Azure Information \n    Protection")) {
    throw new UnsupportedAzurePdfFormatException("Microsoft Azure protected pdf is not supported.");
}
```